# Animate marker in Google Maps SDK in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps, gmsmapview

I have an image over a map and I want to give it some linear and rotational motion over the google maps.

How can I do it in GMS? Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543095/bounce-animation-on-google-map-marker-in-ios-objective-c/41764821#41764821 animate google marker in iOS

Answer (score 2):

You could add the image as a marker and then use the layer property of that marker to add some animations using `CoreAnimation`

See the docs: [developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/](http://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference)

Comment: I'm aware of that. There's a layer property on GMSMarker that allows you animate it. I just animated a marker using it. See the docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_map_layer

Comment: SORRY! wasnt aware they added that -- we are still on a very old version

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved the problem by using following code and GMSMarker method setPosition: . 
The following code provides rotation to the images and using setPosition: we can place the marker/image anywhere.
The combination of both gives required linear and rotational motion.

```
- (UIImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees image: (UIImage*) image
{
    CGSize size = image.size;;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0.5f * size.width, 0.5f * size.height ) ;
    CGContextRotateCTM (context, DegreesToRadians(degrees));

    [ image drawInRect:(CGRect){ { -size.width * 0.5f, -size.height * 0.5f }, size } ] ;
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but my marker icon seems shrinked. Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: @RahulVyas That could be the case if your image is not square. Try changing `0.5` multiplier.

Comment: Tried another thing that worked. Do you know how we can smoothly rotate the car in moving direction like uber does ? I am updating heading values on my server.

Comment: @RahulVyas You will have to use web sockets for location of cars. Basically what you need is a persistent connection between the server and the app.

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy process. First rotate the marker to get the right heading using this function:

```
+(float)getBearing:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locations1 andSecond:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)locattion2{
    float fLat = degreesToRadians(locations1.latitude);
    float fLng = degreesToRadians(locations1.longitude);
    float tLat = degreesToRadians(locattion2.latitude);
    float tLng = degreesToRadians(locattion2.longitude);

    float degree = radiansToDegrees(atan2(sin(tLng-fLng)*cos(tLat), cos(fLat)*sin(tLat)-sin(fLat)*cos(tLat)*cos(tLng-fLng)));

    if (degree >= 0) {
        return degree;
    } else {
        return 360+degree;
    }
}
```

Then rotate your marker to the new heading:

```
YOUR_MARKER.rotation = CALCULATED_HEADING - 180;
```

Now, the final step is to animate your driver smoothly

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:3.1];
[YOUR_MARKER setPosition:NEW_LOCATION_COORDINATES];
[CATransaction commit];
```