# Bounce Animation on Google Map Marker in iOS ?? [Objective-c]

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, animation

I  want a Continuos Bounce animation on  Google Map Marker in iOS.

[animation like below link , Click on Marker -->] ,

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations

can we  implement this bounce animation in iPhone?

i am Creating Marker with animated appear but  i want to animate marker with Bounce Effect Continuously.

```
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"Delhi";
marker.zIndex=1;
marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_user.png"];
// This is Only AppearAniamtion
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop; 
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, 0.30f);
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to add marker on Google map which will animate to indicated the current user. 
I was not able to get exact  bounce animation like the link above i mentioned , for alternate way to highlight marker i did with using scale animation.
like this ...
[image]

To get animation like this . do like this

```
 GMSMarker *markerUser;
 NSTimer *timer;
 int imageScale;
```

**Add Marker** on Map

```
 imageScale=15;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Userlat, Userlng);
    markerUser = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
    markerUser.title = @"You are here";
    markerUser.icon=[self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_user.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(25.0f,40.0f)];   // Initial Marker Size
    markerUser.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    markerUser.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.44f, 0.30f);
    markerUser.map = mapView_;
```

**Start Timer** when marker is added on map, and change the icon of marker with different size .

```
 timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

at every 0.1 seconds tragetMethod will be fired , here you can **scale the icon image and reassign to marker icon**

```
-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {

    if (imageScale<30) {

        markerUser.icon=[self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_user.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(imageScale,imageScale*1.5)];

        imageScale+=1;

    }
    else{
        imageScale=15;

         markerUser.icon=[self image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"marker_user.png"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(imageScale,imageScale*1.5)];
    }

}
```

and here is the **method that will** **scale your** `UIImage`

```
- (UIImage *)image:(UIImage*)originalImage scaledToSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //avoid redundant drawing
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(originalImage.size, size))
    {
        return originalImage;
    }

    //create drawing context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);

    //draw
    [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height)];

    //capture resultant image
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return image
    return image;
}
```

This may solve problem of guys looking for such animation.