# MapBox iOS Animated Marker

Tags: ios, animation, mapbox, marker

I'm hoping to implement `MapBox's iOS SDK` into my `Swift` project. If you are familiar with `MapBox` can you please provide advice on the best way of implementing a **marker animation**. I essentially would like the marker to do exactly what iOS maps does when tapped:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: you can see the animating marker  in `GoogleMap` , similarly ,you can also animate in     `MapBox` , i hope 
 this will help you out ,,,, but not sure about the `MapBox` 
 have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543095/bounce-animation-on-google-map-marker-in-ios-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

I done this by creating a subclass of `MGLAnnotationView`, let's call it `CustomView`.

It contains 2 UIImageViews which frame are equal to the `CustomView`'s frame: 1 is the small pin, default alpha = 1, and 1 is the large pin, default alpha = 0. You have to override the `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` method to get the animation you want.

After that, implement `func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView?` to return your `CustomView`.