# I want to shake the google map marker in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am working on a project where I wants to shake the marker on google Map.
I am using the custom marker icon to represent on the map.
Like a head of person is shaking.
I don't know how to do it and search a lot but didn't find any solution.

Comment: You need animation of shake horizontal or vertical?

Comment: you can use the Rotation property of marker ,

Comment: you can do this way also 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543095/bounce-animation-on-google-map-marker-in-ios-objective-c

Comment: I want to shake horizontally @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `CAKeyframeAnimation` or `CABasicAnimation` to your `marker.iconView!.layer` we add a UIView with a frame bigger than our UIImageView inside then we need to adjust the anchor point of your UIImageView to bottom in vertical and horizontally centered this will be the point that will work as pivot in our animation, our animation will be a rotation animation in Z plane from -30 to 30 grades to achieve the animation desired.This is the simplest way to do this but you can also define a custom class and make a lot of other things

```
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 22.404963, longitude: -79.961755))

    //we need a bigger UIView to avoid the clip problem with the UIImageView
    marker.iconView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 40))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (marker.iconView?.frame.width)!/2 - 14, y: (marker.iconView?.frame.height)! - 36, width: 28, height: 36))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "iconomapa")
    marker.iconView?.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0) //we need adjust anchor point to achieve the desired behavior
    imageView.layer.frame = CGRect(x: (marker.iconView?.frame.width)!/2 - 14, y: (marker.iconView?.frame.height)! - 36, width: 28, height: 36) //we need adjust the layer frame

    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    animation.keyPath = "transform.rotation.z"
    animation.values = [ 0, -30 * .pi / 180.0, 30 * .pi / 180.0 , 0]
    animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.33 , 0.66 , 1]
    animation.duration = 1;
    animation.isAdditive = false;
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
    animation.repeatCount = .infinity

    marker.iconView!.subviews[0].layer.add(animation, forKey: "shakeAnimation")
    marker.map = self.mapView
```

## here is how it looks

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Reinier
But I am getting nil on 
marker.iconView!.layer.add(animation, forKey: "shakeAnimation")

Comment: @ParthDhorda My answer was updated, you need replace iconomapa by your marker image name

Comment: I want the pin should remain on the same lat & long but the head should me shaking not whole pin

Thanks

Comment: @ParthDhorda you have the pin and the head as separated images?

Comment: There is one single pin on the marker and want the shaking like this  [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKq_Yak3rcI)

Comment: but you want rotate then instead of horizontal movement, is the first thing I ask you

Comment: Thanks Reinier But I am still get error on this line ---  marker.iconView!.subviews[0].layer.add(animation, forKey: "shakeAnimation")

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the help

Comment: @ParthDhorda please post the error that are you receiving

Comment: I was receiving the error as I have taken the Marker object globally and was assigning the values to locally created marker

Thanks again for your help

Comment: can you provice jump animation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use marker property to rotate your marker ,

```
marker.rotation =  (you_angle_in_degree) * M_PI / 180.0f; 
 //  convert  degree to radian
```

The **Horizontally Shake** animation you can get after some time interval change the degree for of the rotation , you can use timer ,

```
  // create a timer
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

 func timerAction() {
       // Place you aniamtion logic here , 
       // every 0.5 second change the rotation of your maker
    }
```